# Seeing other applications' fonts

Tags: windows, fonts

We've gotten one or two complaints about our Windows desktop application's font sizes, and now I'm curious to compare its font selection and size to other applications.

I know that the [Windows UX Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx) has its own recommendations, but I'd like to see what's used in practice.

I know that I can use a tool like Spy++ to inspect window classes, styles, and messages.  Are there any similar tools to identify Windows applications' fonts?